# How to configure chrome's URL suggestions

Tags: google-chrome, autocomplete

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I delete previously entered items from Google Chrome Omnibox?](https://superuser.com/questions/189331/how-do-i-delete-previously-entered-items-from-google-chrome-omnibox)

I prefer to navigate the web with the keyboard, typing in URLs and letting Chrome autocomplete them. How can I stop Google's autocomplete from suggesting specific URLs? There are a few old URLs that keep popping up that I'd like to get rid of. Here's an example:

Typing `calendar.google.com` will take me to Google Calendar. Typing the first few letters *should* take me where I want to go. However, several months ago, I accidentally typed `calendar.com`, which isn't where I want to be at all. That site keeps popping up in my autocomplete list.

Is it possible to get rid of this entry? Preferably, without clearing the rest of the list. There's nothing in the Chrome settings about this that I can find. There *must* there a list somewhere I can edit, yes? Maybe a preference file or a cache?

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I delete previously entered items from Google Chrome Omnibox?](http://superuser.com/questions/189331/how-do-i-delete-previously-entered-items-from-google-chrome-omnibox).

Answer (score 2):

Just go to the web address when typing in address bar using arrow keys and press the <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>del</kbd> key on Windows to delete the specific URL from address bar.

For the Mac you have to hold <kbd>Fn</kbd> key along with <kbd>Shift</kbd> key. And its work like a charm for others.

Comment: That's shift + fn + delete on a Mac, but I'm afraid it doesn't work for me.

Comment: This does work, but I think it only works from a new tab window.  If I have a page loaded, it won't let me delete the suggestions.  Also, I couldn't get it to work with the mouse... only by arrowing down with the keyboard.

Comment: Ah, sorry I didn't mind that you are using Mac. @techturtle thanks that is a good point.

Comment: @techturtle yeas it won't let you delete at the loaded time because process in use so you have to delete it through the **New Tab**

Comment: @neilfein updated it as you said in your comment. However it works for other users so it will for you too.

Comment: Down voter please comment what is the wrong with the answer.