# How to delete an URL from Chrome's Omnibox suggestions?

Tags: google-chrome, privacy, history, autocomplete, address-bar

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I delete previously entered items from Google Chrome Omnibox?](https://superuser.com/questions/189331/how-do-i-delete-previously-entered-items-from-google-chrome-omnibox)
>   [Chrome: remove URL from autocomplete which doesn't show up in history?](https://superuser.com/questions/328515/chrome-remove-url-from-autocomplete-which-doesnt-show-up-in-history)

How can I delete an URL from Chrome's Omnibox suggestions?

The URLs won't be deleted even if I clear my entire browsing history. I've also tried deleting the "History Provide Cache" file, but to no avail.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 97):

Follow the next steps:

- Clear the omnibar
- Start writing the address that gives you the unwanted history item
- As soon as the history item apears below the omnibar use the down arrow to select it
- Press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Del</kbd> (or <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Del</kbd> if on a Mac)

Comment: No. It is `Shift + Del`. Look at the edit I've made.

Comment: At the address bar.

Comment: What Chrome version are you using? I rewrite the answer.

Comment: @criziot I can confirm this solution. Thank you for clarifying your steps.

Comment: @criziot: I'm not sure if this is what the OP was talking about, but I'm incredibly grateful for this answer.

Comment: Is this still functional? Doesn't seem to work for me on chrome 21.0.1180.89

Comment: @DevinGRhode I don't know about 21.0.1180.89 but I just tried on 22.0.1229.79 and yes, it wors. Sometimes the website still on the list but can be from google search or favorites and not from history.

Comment: it actually worked for me, I just needed to hold down `fn` for mac.

Comment: Wrong answer. Not valid. This method is obsolete. I have a PC. No fn button. This answer used to work but Google removed this functionality.

Comment: @techaddict not really, it still works for me (version 40.0.2214.111). In a PC you don't need Fn, that's for Mac.

Comment: DOES NOT WORK ON MAC EL CAPITAN.

Comment: @LexPodgorny Why are you shouting at us?

Comment: Yes, it does work on Mac OS El Capitan (Fn + Shift + Delete)

Comment: No worky on Chrome on my PC for some reason