# Make Chrome suggest ALL history results and NO web suggestions in omnibox

Tags: google-chrome, history, omnibox

For various reasons, I like to completely disable omnibox suggestions from the web. However, I would like to get ALL matching results from my own browser history as suggestions (a behaviour that was the default years ago). I would appreciate help with this.

I am aware of the solutions posted to similar (but not the same) questions from the past, e.g. [Make Chrome prioritize history results over search suggestions in omnibox](https://superuser.com/questions/802597/make-chrome-prioritize-history-results-over-search-suggestions-in-omnibox). I appreciate these, but they don't completely solve my problem.